# formatting date in mule 4 Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am using now() to get current datetime in Dataweave, I would like to format it so special character are removed and I get plain format like this 20200723T1720334450200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
now() as String {"format": "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSSSSSS"}
```